# Display emoticons and special character in generated PDF from HTML content using wicked_pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I'd like to show special characters and emoticons in my pdf using wicked gem but the charset of my generated PDF is UTF-8.

**pdf gem:** https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

```
# base_pdf
doctype html
html lang="#{I18n.locale}"
  head
    meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"
    meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    = wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf"
    = wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "app"
  body onload="number_pages"
    #content
      = yield
```

I would like emoticons like these (and not blank symbols) to appear in my pdf:

```
 This is    Hot Dog  Hamburgers
```

I would be grateful for your time.

Comment: wicked_pdf uses wkhtmltopdf in the background and it looks like it's a known issue: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2913